# Problem with the convergence of a Nystrom algorithm

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

I programmed a Nystrom Algorithm specifically for my problem:

This is the exact equation i want to solve:

$y''=(w^2-e*cos(t))*sin(t)-b*y'$

And this is my algorithm

```
function [T U] = Nystrom(a,b,u0,h,w,v,e)
    % a is the initial value
    % b is the final value
    % u0 is a vector with the initial conditions y(0) and y'(0)
    % h is the size of every step
    % w, v and e are constants.

    M=(b-a)/h+2; %Steps
    T=zeros(1,M+2); %Time vectors
    U=zeros(2,M+2); %y and y' vector
    T=a:h:b; % i use uniform steps of size h
    U(:,1)=u0; %i stablish the initial conditions

    U(1,2)=U(1,1)+h*U(2,1)+(h^2)/2 * (w^2-e*cos(T(1))*sin(U(1,1))-v*U(2,1));

    for i=3:M
        U(1,i)=(-2*U(1,i-1)+U(1,i-2)-h^2*(w^2-e*cos(T(i-1)))*sin(U(1,i-1))-h*v*(U(1,i-2))/2)/(1-h*v/2);
    end

    for i=1:M
        U(2,i+1)=(U(1,i+2)-U(1,i))/(2*h);
    end

    U=U';
    T=T';
```

The problem is, it doesn't work and i don't know why. It's throwing values bigger and bigger in every step, but solving the same problem with other methods gives different, quite smaller values.

Any idea could help. Thank you!

Comment: Dear Federico, try http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/
Yo may get an answer there more quickly.

Comment: First of all: Why is it $\sin(U(\dots))$ when the equation reads $\sin t$? Which one is a typo?